# How to fix the output after I compare two arrays in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, for-loop, output

So I have this homework assignment that requires me to assign output to labels after I compare two arrays. My problem is that after I compare the two arrays, the output I assign is wrong. I'm supposed to out 'Y' if at a specific index of the two arrays are equal and 'N' if they're not equal but every time I run the code, it outputs 'Y' to all the labels no matter what. How can I fix what is being outputted after the comparison?

```
     private void evaluateStudentAnswers()
        {
            /* Use a "for" loop to cycle through the answerKey[] and studentAnswers[] arrays, and compare the answers
             * in the two arrays at each index.  If they match, then increment the global variable "correctAnswers"
             * and assign the value 'Y' to the corresponding index in the correctOrIncorrect[] array.  if they
             * don't match, then increment the global variable "incorrectAnswers" and assign the value 'N' to the
             * corresponding indes in the correctOrIncorrec[] array.  These two variables will be used to calculate
             * the grade percentage.
             */

            for (int i = 0; i < studentAnswers.Length; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < answerKey.Length; j++)
                {
                    // I think the indexes below are being checked if they're the same and I need to make sure not just the
                    //indexes are the same but the values as well 
                    if (studentAnswers[i] == answerKey[j]) 
                    {
                        correctAnswers++;

                        for(int k = 0; k < correctOrIncorrect.Length; k++)
                        {
                            correctOrIncorrect[k] = 'Y';
                        }
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        incorrectAnswers++;

                        for (int k = 0; k < correctOrIncorrect.Length; k++)
                        {
                            correctOrIncorrect[k] = 'N';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Its because of your `correctOrIncorrect` for loops. Are studentAnswers.Length == answerKey.Length == correctOrIncorrect.Length? If so, its can be simplified greatly.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. If you're asking if the length of the studentAnswers, answerKey, and correctOrIncorrect arrays are all equal, then yes they are all equal sized arrays @SILENT.

Comment: If you are allowed to use LINQ check out the `Zip` method: you can 'zipper' the two arrays together, create a tuple or anonymous type from each pair and then compare the two properties making this a two liner (second line would count the Ys and Ns).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your code can be simplified quite a lot. assuming there's a 1-1 mapping between `studentAnswers` and `answerKey`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < studentAnswers.Length; i++)
{
    var studentAnswer = studentAnswers[i];
    var answer = answerKey[i];
    if (studentAnswer == answer)
    {
        ++correctAnswers;
        correctOrIncorrect[i] = 'Y';
    }
    else
    {
        ++incorrectAnswers;
        correctOrIncorrect[i] = 'N'
    }
}
```

All of the arrays are the same size. So when we loop over each answer the student provided, we know we can find the corresponding correct answer in `answerKey`. Also, the tracking of correct answers also follows the same pattern, for each `studentAnswer`, we want to record the correctness in `correctOrIncorrect`, which corresponds to the particular answer the student provided. As such, we only need to perform a single loop, since the `i` refers to the appropriate index in all the arrays as we're processing.

Answer (score 1):

If studentAnswers.Length == answerKey.Length == correctOrIncorrect.Length

Then

```
for (int i = 0; i < studentAnswers.Length; i++)
{
  if(studentAnswers[i] == answerKey[j])
  {
    correctAnswers++;
    correctOrIncorrect[k] = 'Y';
  }
  else
  {
    incorrectAnswers++;
    correctOrIncorrect[k] = 'N';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it is an assignment I wont give an answer :) but since you are stuck I encourage you use the guidance below.

These two are unnecessary in your code

1. inner for-loop on correctOrIncorrect[]
2. variable "k", you can use "i" instead for correctOrIncorrect value assignment

Answer (score 1):

Since the arrays have to have the same size/order, you only need to loop through them once. Also I find ternary assignments more clear than if blocks:

```
Func<bool, int> toInt = (b) => b ? 1 : 0;
for (int i = 0; i < studentAnswers.Length; i++)
{
    var studentAnswer = studentAnswers[i];
    var answer = answerKey[i];
    var isCorrect = studentAnswer == answer;
    correctOrIncorrect[i] = isCorrect ? 'Y' : 'N';
    correctAnswers = isCorrect ? 1 : 0; // toInt(isCorrect)
    incorrectAnswers = !isCorrect ? 1 : 0; // toInt(!isCorrect)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or in LINQ (just because it's worth learning, but probably not appropriate for homework):

```
correctOrIncorrect = answerKey.Zip(studentAnswer, (a,b) => a == b ? "Y" : "N").ToArray();
incorrectAnswers = correctOrIncorrect.Count(x => x == "Y");
...
```